# Which open-source Python or Java library provides an easy way to draw circles on a ESRI Shapefile?

Tags: java, python, arcgis, shapefile, esri

I need to write a software that creates an shapefile with various circles or circumferences on it.
The shapefile created should be readable by ESRI ArcMap.

I need a library that let me add circles or circular arc to it.

The library could be in for Python or in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [OpenMap](http://openmap.bbn.com/), it may be possible to write some code using that set of libraries in Java to do what you are asking.

I don't know if its possible from a single call, but there is definitely code in OpenMap to [generate circles and arcs](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/geo/package-summary.html) and it also has code to read in a shapefile.  The jump to [exporting a shape file](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/dataAccess/shape/output/package-summary.html) shouldn't be too big.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Perry has a short and sweet example of creating circles in a shapefile in [Tissot Indicatrix - Examining the distortion of map projections](http://www.perrygeo.net/wordpress/?p=4). Not listed in the post is how to install the prerequiste gdal/ogr; for that see [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki) on windows or a simple `apt-get install gdal python-gdal` on ubuntu linux.